# Keep only superclass variables after casting subclass to superclass

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have two class

BaseClass

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public int baseClassVariable = 10;
    //like this 10 to 20 variables
}
```

SubClass

```
public class SubClass extends BaseClass
{
    public int subClassVariable = 20;
    //like this 30 to 40 variables
}
```

And a main class:

```
public class TestMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<String, BaseClass> myData = new HashMap<String, BaseClass>();
        SubClass mydata = new SubClass();
        myData.put("Test", mydata);
        for (Entry<String, BaseClass> data : myData.entrySet())
        {
            System.out.println(data.getKey() + "-" + data.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, in my main class I have the `Map` of `String` and the `BaseClass`. My expectation is to keep less memory footprint, so I need to keep only `BaseClass` variables in memory which are frequently used data in the application, but subclass is needed in application for some computation so in the application the subclass will be created.

Now my question it is the best way (superclass and subclass) to archive my expectation (now it is not working as per expectation because on inheritance) or do I need to user different mechanism to achieve it.

My final goal is to keep only `BaseClass` variables in map.

Comment: This does not save memory in the way you think. The values in the map are still `SubClass` objects, even though the type of the values in the map is `BaseClass`. The `SubClass` part is not somehow thrown away if you do this.

Comment: Indeed. Casting doesn't change the type of the object - if you want to create just a `BaseClass` object, you'll need to do that explicitly.

Comment: @Jesper yes even after casting SubClass to BaseClass the class will not be converted this is correct but how i can achieve this type of requirement is there is any other way.?

Comment: If you want to keep the `BaseClass` fields and discard the `SubClass` fields, maybe inheritance isn't the model you want. It would be easy to discard the `SubClass` data if it was not bound into the same object as your `BaseClass` data.

Comment: @khelwood but my application need whole data from SubClass and BaseClass so that only i had used like this, is there is any other way to do this instead of splitting this two classes.?

Comment: If your application needs all the data, how can you conserve memory like your proposal? The data does not vanish from memory when you cast, because (with the correct checks) you can cast back. The data needs to be available to the application, so it needs to be stored somewhere, in your current example this will always be memory. You can also use a data storage like a db, filesystem to store the data out of memory... Keep in mind though that retrieving the data from fs or db is way more costly then retrieving from memory.

Comment: @stech What does this mean "my application need whole data from `SubClass` and `BaseClass`? You can still have all the data from those two classes. What exactly are the requirements?

Comment: @JohannisK my application need all the variables in both class but the SubClass venerable can be constricted using run time bu the BaseClass variables can't be so that only base class variables are preserved.

Comment: When your BaseClass is instantiated it will initialise all it's variables. It's not Abstract, so this will work just fine. Where does the data for initialisation come from? Are these static values, or are they retrieved from a web service or database?

Comment: @JohannisK BaseClass variables are taken from first webservice but subsequent web service don't have this data so that only i am keeping in the map for using in subsequent services.

Comment: @stech So in short, you want to use all fields of `SubClass`, and at some point in time, you want to get rid of all data of the `SubClass`, leaving only the fields of the `BaseClass` in memory?

Comment: Keep in mind though (whichever solution you choose) when the data leaves the memory it's not accesible by the Application anymore. It will need to be retrieved from a datasource again.

Comment: @MCEmperor yes , but i know the current way what i am doing it is not possible but is there is any other way to achieve this.?

Answer (score 0):

Casting does not modify objects in any way. It is a compile-time operation that tells the compiler that it can expect an object to have the fields and methods of a specific type - in this case a superclass.

In order to 'convert' an object from a subclass type to a superclass type, what you can do is have a constructor which accepts a superclass instance, like so:

```
public BaseClass(BaseClass template){
   baseClassVariable=template.baseClassVariable;
   // ... and so forth for all fields
}
```

Note that you can pass a subclass instance to the constructor. Since it will only copy its 'known' fields, this will still yield a superclass instance with only the superclass fields.

Also note that for non-primitive types, simply copying the reference might be dangerous, as both the original instance and the newly created instance still reference the same fields. For complex data structures, you may need to deep copy the referenced fields, e.g. via `Object.clone()`.

Answer (score -1):

Casting does not do the job you're expecting to be done.

You have a few options:

- Copy all values-to-be-preserved into another object:

  ```
  public PreservedData(WholeBunchOfData data) {
      this.somevar = data.somevar;
      // Copy the values to be preserved manually
  }
  ```
- Use a separate object to put the disposable values in:

  ```
  class BaseClass {
      int valueToBePreserved = 29;
      String otherValueToBePreserved = "";
      DisposableObjectContainingDisposableValues someDisposableObj = ...;
  }

  class SubClass {
      int disposableValue = 13;
      String someOtherDisposableValue = 47;
  }
  ```

  When you're done with it, just set the object to null.

  ```
  this.someDisposableObj = null;
  ```

  It will be soon garbage collected.

You should, however, consider whether the gain is bigger than the cost. If it's just a number of primitive values or of not very big objects, it's likely that it won't be that much memory.